# Android-Quiz App with SqliteAssetHelper

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've started to develop a quiz application (multiple and single choice) for android.
The reason why I chose the SqliteAssetHelper library is, that I want a prepopulated database. 
I've created a sqlite database with 2 tables (question & answer).

[image: question & answer table]

With the following method in my database class I'm getting the question items:

```
public Cursor getQuestionItems() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    qb.setTables(TABLES.QUESTION);
    Cursor questionCursor = qb.query(db, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    return questionCursor;
}
```

In the main class (in onCreate) I'm creating question objects and add them to the arraylist:

```
    Cursor questionCursor = db.getQuestionItems();
    while (questionCursor.moveToNext()) {
        Question question = new Question();
        question.setId(
                questionCursor.getString(questionCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabase.QuestionColumns.ID)));
        question.setQuestiontext(questionCursor
                .getString(questionCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabase.QuestionColumns.QUESTIONTEXT)));
        question.setQuestiontype(questionCursor
                .getInt(questionCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabase.QuestionColumns.QUESTIONTYPE)));

        questionList.add(question);
    }

    questionCursor.close();
```

I'm doing the same also for the answer items. Now I want to show a view with a question and the possible answers (for example 4 answers). If the user clicks on the "next"-button the next question with the answers should be displayed.

How can I achieve this efficiently? Is it at all necessary to create question and answer items? I'm not sure if this is the right way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To follow database rules, we should do like that. One table for questions, one table for answers as per the structure provided by you. Its the better way, because you will follow the database rule and there will not be redudant data. But when displaying the answer, display the data for proper question ID.

Comment: Ok and do I need to create the items and add them to the arraylist? To display the data by questionId: should I make a database query like qb.setTables("Question INNER JOIN Answer ON (Question.id = Answer.qid)")? Or should I search for the questionid in my arraylist. This is the point I don't understand

Comment: @DenoAgüero You can use this to query from database `qb.setTables("Question LEFT OUTER JOIN Answer ON (Question.id = Answer.qid)")`.